# Catching only programmatic errors in sql azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have code like this in my Worker Role:

```
           try
           {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                     connection.Open();
                    //...
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
           }
           catch (SqlException sqlEx)
           {
           }
```

and I want to catch here only programmatic errors not something which is coming from db connection problem or throttling.

Is there any way to check it and filter only real db related problems e.g. constraint violation?

Answer (score 0):

```
  catch (SqlException sqlEx)
           {
           }
```

The above code will catch all the exception.
And it will be a complex setup to filter out messages.

[image]

> It is recommended to catch the issue and not to suppress them

Comment: Problem is that I need to repeat code after some time in the case of connection problem or throttling. For programmatic errors there is no sense to repeat the execution.

Comment: Keep some status in database to check multiple insertions or you can add keys in tables

Comment: I has nothing to do with keys or insertions I am searching for general pattern how to filter out physical and programmatic problems.

Comment: What for sense has text Forced Exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to throw based off the type of error using `SqlException.Number`.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx.

For example:

```
catch(SqlException sqlEx) {
  if (sqlEx.Number == expectedException) {
    //don't throw
  } else {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Note: You may also want to check each error number in SqlException.Errors to be even more careful.  Per [SqlException.Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) documentation:

> This is a wrapper for the Number property of the first SqlError in the Errors property

Comment: I dont have any information about numbers for throttling and connection errors. (sqlazure not sqlserver)

Comment: Maybe this would help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394106.aspx?